# How can I Eject CashDrawer with Android?

Tags: android, linux

Could you give me some idea to eject cash drawer by Android ?

Other people use DOS to eject it, but Android is a Linux Kernel. My device is "Acer Iconia tab a500 + usb cash drawer.

Answer (score 2):

What's the cash drawer's input? Does it directly have a USB cable, or is it plugging into a USB driven receipt printer? Many cash drawers don't actually have a USB interface of their own, instead they expect to plug into something like a receipt printer that has USB connection, and which provides the right signal to energize the cash drawer's solenoid when a certain character is printed.

First step I'd do is to plug the USB thing (whether it's the cash drawer or the receipt printer) into a PC and figure out what sort of device it is (I'd guess that it probably shows up as a serial port, because that would be easy for the developers to do). Once you know what sort of USB device you're dealing with, then you'll need to figure out how to make the Android device talk to that sort of USB device.

For making an Android device control USB devices, I'd look into the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) because that seems to have what is needed.

If the cash drawer does NOT actually have a USB connector, but instead has something like an ethernet or phone connector, then the cash drawer ISN'T USB. Instead, it's expecting whatever it is plugged into to energize it's solenoid with a pulse on some of the wires on that connector. You'll have to look at the spec sheets (or take it apart) to figure out how to energize it properly.

Comment: Thank you , for your suggestion , i'll try to work hard with these : )  

last time i got some idea to print out with wireless printer 

it's a good idea to work with it .

Comment: perhaps take a look at Raspberry PI or similar hardware which you might be able to setup as a cheap server solution combining receipt printer and cash drawer, then let the Raspberry PI run a service that will allow the Android to connect to the PI and send an "eject command" you build into the service.